# Appending variables with quotes and space in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I would like to run a command in a bash script with arguments however the arguments are conditional. What I would like to achieve is this

`command --myflag var="value with space"`

In the case above I would like to have `--myflag var="value with space"` conditional and it also has to have the double-quotes because of the space (among other reasons). So I attempted something like this

```
if [ $somecondition ]; then
  FLAG="--myflag var=\"value with space\""
fi

command $FLAG
```

When I run the above in debug I can see that is run is this

```
command --myflag 'var="value' with 'space"'
```

Notice the single quotes. I dont know why this is but after several attempts at trying this I seem to fail to find a solution,

How would one go about solving this?

Comment: [How do I store a command in a variable?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use [Bash array extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). Something like:

```
declare -a FLAG
if [ $somecondition ]; then
  FLAG=(--myflag 'var="value with space"')
fi
command "${FLAG[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks you. Took a little while to figure out the correct syntax but bash arrays worked